# Replacing function with inline assembly C

Tags: c, assembly, clang, inline-assembly

I've got a function whose inner code I want to convert into assembly (for various reasons):

```
int foo(int x, int y, int z);
```

I generated the assembly code using:

```
clang -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel foo.c
```

The assembly output: foo.s starts off with something like:

```
_foo:                               ## @foo
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    push    RBP
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
...
```

I assume this is the corresponding assembly code for that function. My question is, what part of the assembly output should I copy into the C code (I'm trying to use inline assembly) so that the function would work? The code should look like:

```
int foo(int x, int y, int z) {
   __asm__("..."); // <-- What goes inside?
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can let your debugger to run on assembly code then you can step on that function and find out actually what part needs to be used. But keep in mind that the complier optimizes a lot of thing so it may not be correct always.

Comment: Hmm, so if I found where the function actually starts, would copy and pasting the assembly code directly into C (wrapped around with __asm__ etc.) work? I won't need to specify operand lists or clobber lists or anything right?

Comment: Unless your asm is tiny and you think it should get inlined, write your whole function in an asm source file, and call it.  (Keep a prototype for it in a C header file of course.)  Then your build system has to know to compile that asm source for x86 and/or x86-64 builds, instead of just with `#ifdef` in C.  Getting inline asm correct, esp. getting the constraints, clobbers, and inputs/outputs exactly right, is hard but required for it to work correctly.  (If you do go that route, check the disassembly output to make sure your ASM is slotting in the way you expect).

Answer (score 1):

You have to see the disassembly of that function and write the `__asm__`. For example below code

`int foo(int x, int y, int z) {

    x = y+z;
    return x;
}`

will yeild a disassembly of following :

```
int foo(int x, int y, int z) {
  push        ebp  
  mov         ebp,esp 
  sub         esp,0C0h 
  push        ebx  
  push        esi  
  push        edi  
  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h] 
  mov         ecx,30h 
  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 

  x = y+z;
  mov         eax,dword ptr [y] 
  add         eax,dword ptr [z] 
  mov         dword ptr [x],eax 

  return x;
  mov         eax,dword ptr [x] 
}
```

so you have to add below for statement `x= y+z`,

```
 mov         eax,dword ptr [y] 
 add         eax,dword ptr [z] 
 mov         dword ptr [x],eax
```

Comment: Okay, I have a slight issue with this, the compiler is complaining that I'm not returning a variable (because I'm returning via assembly), any way to solve this?

Comment: Include the `mov         eax,dword ptr [x] ` , it worked.         `int foo(int x, int y, int z) {
  
 x = y+z;
 _asm{
  mov         eax,dword ptr [x] 
 }
 
}`

Comment: Are you using MSVC for compiling? Do you know to do the same thing with clang?

Comment: yes. Clang I never used before. But,

Clang-based C++ compilers allow inline assembly with these caveats:
You cannot mix assembly with C++ code.
Do not touch the stack pointer (RSP).
The assembler must use the AT&T line-by-line syntax, not the more familiar block-of-Intel syntax. For more information, see GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.
Clang-based C++ compilers support inline assembly in a different style than the inline assembly supported by BCC32:
The Assembly syntax supported by Clang-based C++ compilers is line-by-line AT&T syntax, not the more familiar block-of-Intel syntax.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Differences_Between_Clang-based_C%2B%2B_Compilers_and_Previous-Generation_C%2B%2B_Compilers

Comment: @Peter: Don't return from inside inline ASM.  I'm not sure if there's any guarantee it's safe when the function body contains nothing but the inline asm, but it's definitely NOT safe if the function has local variables that would get allocated on the stack.  The stack pointer would be pointing to the wrong stuff for a `ret` at that point.

Comment: Did you compile that example with no optimization on?  Because that asm is a poor starting point.  It even led you to include a useless instruction.  It stores to `x` on the stack, and loads it right back.  You should just leave the result in `eax`, which is the return value in SysV and Windows x86 and x86-64 ABIs.  `gcc -O3 -m32` compiles the whole function to `movl 12(%esp), %eax;    addl 8(%esp), %eax;   ret`.  Note how the first parameter (`4(%esp)`) is ignored, because you never read the passed-in value of `x`.  x86-64 compiled version:  `leal (%rsi,%rdx), %eax;  ret`.